# Controller's computed property invoke (depends on checked property) in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

There is an example [in documetation](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/marking-a-model-as-complete-incomplete/). The code is [here](http://jsbin.com/UDoPajA/1/edit).

The documentation talks that *isCompleted* controller's computed property will be called with argument wich value is either *true* or *false* depends on checked input property's value.

How does controller automatically knows that is checked property of input is changed? I mean it's so unobvious that controller's cumputed property will be called when checked input property's state changes. How it works? Where the documentation describes this behavior?

Big thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The controller doesn't know, the input helper binds the checkbox to the passed in argument `checked`.

```
{{input type="checkbox" checked=isCompleted class="toggle"}}
```

http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/input-helpers/

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Checkbox.html

```
Ember.Checkbox = Ember.View.extend({
  classNames: ['ember-checkbox'],

  tagName: 'input',

  attributeBindings: ['type', 'checked', 'indeterminate', 'disabled', 'tabindex', 'name'],

  type: "checkbox",
  checked: false,
  disabled: false,
  indeterminate: false,

  init: function() {
    this._super();
    this.on("change", this, this._updateElementValue);
  },

  didInsertElement: function() {
    this._super();
    this.get('element').indeterminate = !!this.get('indeterminate');
  },

  _updateElementValue: function() {
    set(this, 'checked', this.$().prop('checked'));
  }
});
```

Comment: please read the question more carefully. your answer is fundamentally not right.

Comment: I read the question just fine, I didn't see it was defined on the controller as well as the model and the link you sent talked about the binding up top to the property. The answer still stands.

Comment: The quote from the documentation:"When this {{input}} is rendered it will ask for the current value of the controller's isCompleted property. When a user clicks this input, it will call the controller's isCompleted property with an argument of either true or false depending on the new checked value of the input." So how you can say that controller doesn't know about checked state changing?

Comment: I responded to your statement of `automatically knowing`, it doesn't automatically know, the input helper binds the checked value to `isCompleted` so when the ui changes the input helper will set the bound property to the state of the checkbox